# SQL Server 2008 Express is not forwarded next rows using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

My question to you guys is if anybody has seen such a behaviour before or if anybody might be able to explain it to me.

**What's the situation?**

We have a table which looks like this:

```
Entry_Date    | Exit_Date    |S_No|  
-----------------------------------
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |1  
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |1  
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |1  
2015-01-30    | 2015-01-30   |1  
2015-01-30    | 2015-01-30   |1  
2015-02-02    | 2015-02-02   |1
```

Multiple object ids are allocated to one `Entry_Date`. The order should be defined by the `Entry_Date` column. The funny part lies exactly in establishing that order. Of course, after doing that the table should look like this:

```
Entry_Date    | Exit_Date    |S_No|  
-----------------------------------
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |1  
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |2  
2015-01-29    | 2015-01-29   |3  
2015-01-30    | 2015-01-30   |1  
2015-01-30    | 2015-01-30   |2  
2015-02-02    | 2015-02-02   |1
```

With that the loop works as expected, the column in question is updated as it should and the cursor will reach the end of the result set.

**The big ?**

Has anyone any explanation for that? There are more cursor defined in the same procedure and they all work as expected. I have absolute no clue how to explain this.

So, thanks for reading ;)

Comment: What loop? - you forgot to post your code. However try to avoid loops and use commands working with whole datasets like `UPDATE ... WHERE ...`

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no such concept as "order" in a table. Only query results have order, and that is true only for queries that have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Row_number()` window function to generate `S_No`

```
select Entry_Date ,Exit_Date, 
       S_No =Row_Number()over(partition by Entry_Date order by Exit_Date)
From Yourtable
```

Comment: Thank's Sir

I shall try it